# Is there an R function for return a vector of the multiple positions matches in 1 cell?

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm trying to match multiple positions from a vector. *Here's the code I've tried:*

```
e$e1(   1   1   2   2   3   3   )
dfm1e1<-match(c(m$m1),c(e$e1)) %>% data.frame(. )
```

Here's the result from when I match as a data frame:

```
1,  3,  1,  3,  5,  NA
```

What I need is such an effect, so not only first but every result in one record:

```
1;2,    3;4,    1;2,    3;4,    5,  NA
```

Also, I'm keeping my data in order by using the `bind_cols()` function:

```
test3<-c(m$m1) %in% e$e1 %>% data.frame(. )
test3<-which(c(m$m1) %in% c(e$e1)) %>% data.frame(. )
```

Comment: There are a few things that don't seem to be valid code, such as `test3% data.frame(. )`. It's unclear how you intend to go from the two vectors (also not shown in valid code) to the output you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you have two vectors:

```
m1<-c( 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4 )
e1<-c( 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 )
```

This will provide a list containing all matches:

```
m <- lapply(m1, function(x) which (e1 == x))

[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 1 2

[[4]]
[1] 3 4

[[5]]
[1] 5 6

[[6]]
integer(0)
```

Which can then be converted into a data frame:

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(m, `length<-`, max(sapply(m, length)))))

  V1 V2
1  1  2
2  3  4
3  1  2
4  3  4
5  5  6
6 NA NA
```

Please let me know if this is what you had in mind.

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you a lot and sorry for late response.

Comment: Glad to hear. If helpful/appropriate, feel free to upvote or accept as answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers